# Oracle XE silent config ignores response file...?

Tags: oracle-database, oracle

I'm trying to configure Oracle XE 11.2 (on Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.6) in "silent mode" via a response file. I'm using the response file provided in the package (`Disk1/response/xe.rsp`), replacing values for `ORACLE_PASSWORD` and `ORACLE_CONFIRM_PASSWORD` with a very simple password (8 alphanumeric characters). I then launch the configuration like this:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure responseFile=/path/to/xe.rsp
```

No matter what I specify in that file though, it just gets ignored; after configuration, I end up with a database I cannot log onto with the credentials I supplied. If I then reset the password for SYSTEM and/or SYS, I can log on fine.

I tried going through /etc/init.d/oracle-xe a bit, and it looks like it's writing response values to a file under /tmp; I checked during a run and that file seems to contain the right values. However, the end result is just not using the supplied credentials.

Has anyone else seen this? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a workaround that seems to work, so I'll post here in case someone else has the same problem.

I created an old-style response file with my values, like this:

```
8080
1521
MyL0ng31337pwd
MyL0ng31337pwd
y
```

Then I just piped it straight into the config script:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure < responses.txt
```

This seems to have done the trick. Note that I've also raised the password length from 8 to 13, so that might also be a factor, but to be honest at this point I really can't be arsed to test further.